# C++ R package error: uploading library

Tags: r, package, rcpp, armadillo

I submitted my package to the CRAN repository. The package was accepted without errors but in the second step of checking the CRAN maintainers reported the following error.

Unfortunately I don't understand how I can fix it.

```
In file included from /Builds/CRAN-QA-Simon/packages/mavericks-x86_64/Rlib/3.3/RcppArmadillo/include/armadillo:23:

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/fstream:864:20: error: 
no member named 'Rf_error' in 'std::__1::codecvt_base'; did you mean simply 'Rf_error'?
    if (__r == codecvt_base::error)
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~

/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/R_ext/Error.h:35:12: note:
'Rf_error' declared here
void NORET Rf_error(const char *, ...);
           ^
```

In my C++ file, I wrote:

```
#include <math.h>      
#include "ANN/ANN.h"     
#include "NN.h"  
#include <R.h>   
#include "RcppArmadillo.h" 

#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
```

How do I have to correct this? Has Rpp.h to be included?

Comment: Your title isn't the most informative. Almost every (?) CRAN package author has had an email from Brian Ripley.

Comment: I was about to point this out as well -- Title also has no bearing on questions content.  Please reword using some variation of the actual error message or problem.

Answer (score 8):

R itself is written in C, due to its early start way back in the early 1990s. C has no namespaces -- which can lead to conflicts as we lack the namespace separation. Identifiers from different libraries sharing the same name can be mistaken.  This has happened here.

R uses, in its C API, functions `length()`, `error()`, .... etc which, given how common the name is, are likely to clash.  So R has as mechanism of prepending `Rf_` to its symbols: `error` becomes `Rf_error`.  This use the preprecessor, which is reasonably dumb (as opposed to using the compiler itself). So when R sees `error` it wants it to be `Rf_error`.

What happens here is that you very likely has `#include <RcppArmadillo.h>` (and therefore the implicit `#include <Rcpp.h>` *before* the include for your actual library.  Try it the other way around.  That way R's messing with its `error()` will not interfere with the library one which is confusing you here.

Comment: I added the part where you suggested to modify but I did not understand how